# How to join tables using include with entity SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I will try to describe my issue in details.I have the following scenario.

1.) I have 3 tables : business, customoffice(Custom Office) and cusdesc(custom office description)

The relationship is that a business has on customoffice and one customoffice has many cusdesc.

The table business has a field customofficeno which is a foreign key  to the field cuscode of the customoffice table.The table cusdesc has a field cuscode which is a foreign key  to the field  cuscode of the customoffice table.

The objective is to select a business including the custom office and custom office description using entity framework.

2.) Code

I have a procedure FillData which fills a datagrid. My objective is to display fields from the 3 tables. I managed to display data from tables "Business" and "Customoffice" but i need to display the description of a custom office via table "cusdesc" and be more specific the field "CSNAME".

3.) My issue is that when I include the ("CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSDESC") the results do not contain data from table "CUSDESC" but only how many records much the criteria so I cannot access the field "CSNAME"

Hereafter is the procedure:

```
using (var _context = new ReftabEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                SetGlobalValues();


                ObjectQuery<BUSINESS> q_business = _context.BUSINESS.Where("it.BUSINESSNO=" + int.Parse(pv_businessno)).Where(string.Format("(it.BUSINESSSTART <= DATETIME'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}') and (it.BUSINESSCLOSED >= DATETIME'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}')", pv_date)).Include("CUSTOMSOFFICE").Include("CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSDESC");


                gvBusinessList.Caption = "Total records selected: " + q_business.Count();
                gvBusinessList.DataSource = q_business;
                gvBusinessList.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorPopup.Text = e.Message;
                errorPopup.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you please give a hint what I do wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Include operator just asks EF to load a related entity with the query. If you don't use "Include", EF will only extract the properties of BUSINESS and will not extract the properties of the CUSTOMSOFFICE. There is no need for the "Include("CONSOMSOFFICE.CUSDESC")" since you already loaded the entire CUSTOMSOFFICE entity in the first Include.

I see that you're binding the result to the grid view, and if I understand correctly, the issue is that the "CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSDESC" is not being displayed in the gridview. I believe this is because the gridview tries to render its representation of the "CUSTOMSOFFICE" object itself, since that's the direct property of the items you are binding. To have more control over the "columns" of your gridview, I suggest using LINQ to transform the results of your query into what you explicitly want to display.

I am assuming that BUSINESSNO, BUSINESSSTART, and BUSINESSCLOSED are properties of your Business entity itself, and that BUSINESSNO is the Primary Key. Let me rewrite your query into this:

```
var q_business = _context.BUSINESS.Include(b=>b.CUSTOMSOFFICE)
                          .Where(p => p.BUSINESSNO == int.Parse(pv_businessno)
                                      && p.BUSINESSSTART <= DateTime.Parse(pv_date)
                                      && p.BUSINESSCLOSED >= DateTime.Parse(pv_date) )
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

This query would extract the details of the Business (including the related CUSTOMSOFFICE details) that matches the given pv_businessno and falls within your date criteria. But you can't bind this to your gridview yet because you might encounter the same problem where the CUSTOMSOFFICE.DESC is not displayed. To ensure proper display, you must identify what properties you want to include. For example, if you only want to display the set of properties below:

1. BUSINESS.BUSINESSNO
2. BUSINESS.BUSINESSNAME
3. BUSINESS.CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSCODE
4. BUSINESS.CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSDESC

You should transform your output to explicitly and immediately include these properties.

```
var q_business = _context.BUSINESS.Include(b=>b.CUSTOMSOFFICE)
                          .Where(b => b.BUSINESSNO == int.Parse(pv_businessno)
                                      && b.BUSINESSSTART <= DateTime.Parse(pv_date)
                                      && b.BUSINESSCLOSED >= DateTime.Parse(pv_date) )
                          .Select(b => new {BusinessNo = b.BUSINESSNO,
                                            BusinessName = b.BUSINESSNAME,
                                            CustomsOfficeCode = b.CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSCODE,
                                            CustomsOfficeDesc = b.CUSTOMSOFFICE.CUSDESC } ) //This Select statement creates a new anonymous type that has Businessno, BusinessName, CustomsOfficeCode, and CustomsOfficeDesc properties
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

When you bind this to your gridview, it should be able to display the value of the CUSDESC property.

Comment: Hi Jeric, Thanks for your immediate response. i will rewrite my code and come back with the results asap.